# Swift String removeSubrange - Protect from Index Error

Tags: swift, string

For a particular section of code, I have:

```
if let endIndex = lineEndIndex {
    buffer.removeSubrange(buffer.startIndex ..< endIndex)
}
```

Unfortunately, I am seeing the following error - *Fatal error: replaceSubrange: subrange extends past String end*

So, I need to guard against this condition with something like this:

```
if (buffer.endIndex < lineEndIndex!) {
    lineEndIndex = buffer.endIndex
}

if let endIndex = lineEndIndex {
    buffer.removeSubrange(buffer.startIndex ..< endIndex)
}
```

However, this seems a bit 'kludgy'.  Is there a more elegant way to guard against trying to go outside the string's length with the *removeSubrange* function?

**Update:**

Based on Leo's second suggestion of using the *min* function, my chunk of code looks like this:

```
// unwrap lineEndIndex
if let endIndex = lineEndIndex {
    // use the smaller of two values, buffer length or endIndex
    let endIndexVal = min(buffer.endIndex, endIndex)

    buffer.removeSubrange(buffer.startIndex ..< endIndexVal)
}
```

Comment: Range checking isn't kludgy unless there is a bug in your code causing the bad index to begin with.

Comment: I know range checking is not kludgy.  Maybe a better ask, is there a more elegant, *swifty* (I am on Swift 3) way to perform range checking than what I have.

Comment: You certainly should be checking `endIndex` and not force-unwrapping `lineEndIndex`.

Comment: you should use index method limitedBy parameter combined with nil coalescing operator and use your string endIndex as the default value. `let lineEndIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: str.endIndex) ?? str.endIndex`

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  Through some process, *lineEndIndex* should be some value that is less than the length of buffer.  However, in the off chance, *lineEndIndex* is greater than the length of buffer, set *lineEndIndex* to the length of buffer in order to prevent an index overflow issue that surfaces as: *Fatal error: replaceSubrange: subrange extends past String end*

Comment: Another option is to use the `min` function `min(buffer.endIndex, lineEndIndex)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
buffer.removeSubrange(buffer.startIndex ..< min(endIndex, buffer.endIndex))
```

That will use the lower of lineEndIndex and the buffer.endIndex and therefore prevent an error if your endIndex is beyond the end of the string.

Comment: this is my comment posted as your answer

Comment: It is indeed.  Sorry about that I was adding it and got distracted.  Then when I finished adding it I hadn't seen the comment.  Although looking at the original lineEndIndex is optional so it should be endIndex.